# Parent element not showing background-color after changing child element's position to absolute

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to apply background-color on the parent element "section" after changing it's position to relative and child element's position to absolute (which should position it relatively to the parent and should also show the background-color behind the parent) but it's like the child element "#searchbar" is moved to the next index (removing it completely from it's parent element "section".

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    section {
      position: relative;
      border: 1px solid black;
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    #searchbar {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      right: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome!</h1>
  <section>
    <form id="searchbar">
      <label for="search">Search:</label>
      <input type="search" id="search" name="search">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!">
    </form>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: when you make that `#searchbar` `position: absolute`, `section` goes empty which means its `width` and `height` is 0 so you can not see background color.

Comment: thanks! that cleared my doubts.

Comment: Absolutely positioned children are ignored in the calculation of parent height. The parent does have red background, but it has a height of 0, that's why you don't see the color. You can either add a fix height to the parent, or use JS to assign  the height of the children to the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the background disappears is that the parent container has suddenly collapsed. There is no height property applied to parent after the child element has been taken out of the document flow with the absolute property, and therefore no height to display your background. Apply a height property and this should fix the issue.